# How do I access such deeply nested object in JS? [JSON]

Tags: node.js, json

I can't access items list in my JSON response from server - when I try to do result.reservations.items or result.reservations.items[0] I get "undefined". How do I access it?

This is what I get after console.log of result.reservations:

```
[ 
 { 
    id: 1,
    reservationDetails: { price: 4970, advance: 1500, },
    items: [ [Object] ],
    client: 
     { 
       id: 8,
       clientType: 'person',
       currency: 'USD',
       guests: [Array] 
    } 
 } 
]
```

Comment: There is no `reservations.items`: `reservations` is an array, so you need to access an array item. For example, there's a `reservations.items[0]`. It's not clear what the issue is beyond that--you inspected the data, you can see what it is, treat it as what it is

Answer (score 1):

reservations is an array of objects. Each reservation object has an attribute named 'items', which is an array of objects. So to get to the first item of the first reservation, you would use: result.reservations[0].items[0]

Comment: You've saved me at least two days! Thank you so much